# When vector grows dynamically, why its not using move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am wondering why the std::vector does not use move constructor when it grows dynamically. Or is it some problem with my code? Please see below my test code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
class test{
public:
    char *ptr; 
public:
    test()
        :ptr{new char[10]}{
            strcpy(ptr,"hello");
            cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
        }
    test(const test& t){
        ptr = new char[10];
        strcpy(ptr,t.ptr);
        cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    test(test &&t){
        this->ptr = t.ptr;
        t.ptr = nullptr;
        cout<<"move constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    ~test(){
        cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};

vector<test> function()
{
    vector<test> v;
    cout<<v.size()<<" "<<v.capacity()<<endl;
    v.push_back(test{});
    cout<<v.size()<<" "<<v.capacity()<<endl;
    v.push_back(test{});
    cout<<v.size()<<" "<<v.capacity()<<endl;
    return v;
}

int main()
{ 
    vector<test> v = function();
}
```

the output of above code is as follows:

```
0 0
constructor called
move constructor called
destructor called
1 1
constructor called
move constructor called
copy constructor called
destructor called
destructor called
2 2
destructor called
destructor called
```

Even though the class `test` has a move constructor, still vector uses copy
constructor when it resizes internally. Is it the expected behavior or is it
because of some problem with `test` class itself?

thanks for your answers.

Comment: Depending on your compiler, the move constructor for class `test` needs to be `noexcept` for `std::vector` to use it.

Comment: It looks like it's moving the object that's already in the vector but using the copy constructor for the new element (since `push_back` takes a const reference).

Comment: @Kevin `push_back` is overloaded to take either `const value_type&` or `value_type&&`.  I think the copy is in fact the object already in the vector.

Comment: @Kevin `push_back` has two overloads one with `const reference` and one with forwarding reference.

Comment: It is all about `noexcept`. Move needs to be `nothrow` to allow `std::vector` to fulfill it's exception guarantees.

Comment: Now that I've actually read the question, I think OP is actually looking for `emplace_back`. Well, a combination of that and `noexcept`. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3500437f1e9f3ea)

Comment: You violate the rule of five (missing assignment operators)

Comment: @101010 and aschepler I didn't realize that C++11 added that. Good to know!

Comment: thank you @AndyG,  by just making the move constructor as noexcept , the vector uses move constructor when it grows dynamically. thank you all.